# Problemas com menu de contexto em listview com spinner

Tags: android

Estou com um problema para abrir um menu de contexto numa listView que tem um spinner.
Fiz o registro da minha lista no onCreate:

```
registerForContextMenu(lista);
```

Criei o menu e adicionei o listener dele:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuItem remover = menu.add("Remover");
    remover.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Mas minha lista é um adapter que eu criei e tenho um spinner em cada linha.
Se eu aperto e seguro em qualquer outro lugar da lista o menu não aparece de jeito nenhum. Mas quando eu aperto e seguro em cima do spinner o menu aparece. Mas não quero menu pro spinner e sim pro item da lista.

Dei uma procurada e recomendaram colocar um setFocusable(false) no spinner. Mesmo assim continuo com o problema. Alguém saber como corrigir isso?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é a forma correta de fazer isso mas achei a solução e talvez ajude outras pessoas.

Como o adaptar foi eu que criei eu entrei no xml e no layout pai que é uma ConstraintLayout eu adicionei a seguinte linha:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Isso resolveu meu problema e agora a linha da lista estava abrindo o menu de contexto.